# USB hub registers hidden keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard

I bought a 4 port USB 2.0 hub with some strange behaviour
When I plug it in I get the following dmesg output:

```
[141240.998931] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[141241.163396] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0000, idProduct=0606
[141241.163398] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[141241.163400] usb 1-5: Product: USB Hub 2.0
[141241.163401] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: USB Hub 2.0
[141241.163528] usb 1-5: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
[141241.163769] hub 1-5:1.0: USB hub found
[141241.163856] hub 1-5:1.0: 5 ports detected
[141241.425732] usb 1-5.5: new full-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[141241.499233] usb 1-5.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0000, idProduct=0606
[141241.499235] usb 1-5.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[141241.499236] usb 1-5.5: Product: USB Hub 2.0
[141241.499237] usb 1-5.5: Manufacturer: USB Hub 2.0
[141241.499306] usb 1-5.5: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
[141241.499953] input: USB Hub 2.0 USB Hub 2.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.5/1-5.5:1.0/0003:0000:0606.0006/input/input11
[141241.500017] hid-generic 0003:0000:0606.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [USB Hub 2.0 USB Hub 2.0] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5.5/input0
```

As you can see it detects a 5 port USB hub but the hub has only 4 physical ports. After it is done detecting the USB hub it detects a new HID device that is connected to the hub on port 5.

Should I toss the hub out or is there a reason for it registering a keyboard? To me that looks kinda fishy. I mean in theory the manufacturer could use this keyboard to download malware.

Comment: ...or the manufacturer might not even know about this.

Comment: Mystery port 5 looks to be the actual connector to your pc, it may also be the driver actually being used by the hub. input hiddev0-human interface device zero, hidraw4-human interface device raw four.

It's wierd, umm weird, i can never spell that rite.